# Do I need to / how do I uninstall integrated graphics before installing card drivers?

Tags: intel-graphics, amd-graphics

I'm using an Intel i3-6100 card which has integrated graphics.
I also have a GPU (Radeon R9 380, lspci | grep VGA adds a Tonga PRO at the beginning) in the mobo but not with installed drivers, leading me to believe my computer currently is running using the integrated graphics, which is not what I want, obviously.

HOWEVER, Settings > Details lists my graphics as a Gallium 0.4 on AMD TONGA (DRM 3.1.0, LLVM 3.8.0)
So, is the computer already using the GPU or should I still install drivers? Do I need to uninstall Intel's onboard graphics? How do I do that? And if I do install the drivers, will the 15.04 driver work for my 16.04 LTS system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default a PCI-E graphics card will be used in preference to an onboard one, older AGP systems sometimes needed this to be manually set in the BIOS but not on newer hardware.

If it is reporting the card in use as the AMD then it is already being used it will be using the open source radeon driver. The AMD proprietary drivers will not work since AMD proprietary drivers have not been updated to support the newer Xorg 1.18.

As for lspci it simply lists devices in the order of their PCI ID numbers so the ordering of that list has nothing to do with which devices are in use or how. Rather it is affected simply by the way the devices are physically connected to the system.

Comment: ok, thanks. If I roll back to Ubuntu 15.04 (which has an AMD Driver) what's the best way to install the AMD Driver?